# cant recieved log object on socket io?

Tags: java, socket.io, netty, slf4j, logback

I have configured logs on socket. I want to read log object(configured on socket) on socket.io(Java). when I execute log-program, socket-io received request but throw following exception.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:103)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:68)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:81)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:198)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:107)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:470)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:351)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:282)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: TIMESTAMP[`

I take code from net. here is a code link: https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ibdknox/socket_io_netty 
server class link.
https://gist.github.com/965499

Answer (score 0):

In [WebSocketServerHandler](https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibdknox/socket_io_netty/WebSocketServerHandler.java), it looks like you want to handle HTTP requests or a WebSocketFrame

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    Object msg = e.getMessage();
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        handleHttpRequest(ctx, (HttpRequest) msg);
    } else if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame) {
        handleWebSocketFrame(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg);
    }
}
```

But in [WebSocketServerPipelineFactory](https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibdknox/socket_io_netty/WebSocketServerPipelineFactory.java), you are using an HttpRequestDecoder.

```
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    // Create a default pipeline implementation.
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
```

If you are using an HttpRequestDecoder you need to at least have a valid HTTP request line plus a Content-Length header.